# Why do my Class constructed variables stay undefined after declaration?

Tags: javascript, node.js, class

I have two scenarios. The first one, when I construct my variables as `constructor(var1, var2){this.var1 = var1; this.var2 = var2`, they are undefined in the rest of the class, like for example with `test(){console.log(this.var1)}`. In the other one, it logs the proper values.

```
class Rectangle {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
  test(){
    console.log(this)
  }
}
const p = new Rectangle(100, 200)

p.test() // => Rectangle { height: 100, width: 200 }

const token = "aaa"
class CatApi {
  constuctor(token, format) { // only xml, html and src; src gives link in response.location header
    this.token = token
    if (format) {
      this.format = format // string allowing xml, html, src and json; default is json
    } else {
      this.format = 'json'
    }

  }
  test(){
    console.log(this)
  }
}
const cat = new CatApi(token, 'json')
cat.test() // => CatApi {}
```

What is happening? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `constuctor(token, format)` you misspelled `constructor`

Comment: In addition to @PatrickEvans' analysis, another potential problem you have is that you have three items with the name `token` in your code. The `const`, the parameter to the constructor, and the property. It's almost always better to use unique names.

Comment: Tyvm, @PatrickEvans, I don't know how I missed that for such a long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled `constructor` in your second class.

Comment: Sheeeit, my observation powers are lacking. Tyvm! I spent like 45 minutes looking at this class without seeing that.